# Compound keys in Ehcache / delete from cache by part key

Tags: java, ehcache

I want to store objects in a `Cache` which use keys that use different objects as a common identifier. This works fine when putting keys into the cache or when looking up entries from the cache.

However, sometimes I want to clear the cache from certain objects. Then I only have parts of the key available. I want to delete all entries that match this part of the key. Is there an easy way of clearing the cache from such entires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got as far as using the [Searchable API](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/search) which works for caches that do not overflow to disk. In my case, there is apparently no solution. I built my own cache now which stands on top of the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) cache where I serialize entries by using a `RemovalListener` and check for the existence of a value stored on disk in the `CacheLoader`. I still experience some minor issuses since the `RemovalListener` is not synchronized on the cache's keys. Otherwise, this works fine. Since Guava caches are less expensive than Ehcaches, this also allows me to create several instances. When I serialize, I create files for each key region such that I can just delete an entire folder if I need to clean up for a compound key value.